# Weighted raster using focal statistics and NbrWeight, but instead of using my kernel file, ArcGIS Pro keeps just using the default weights

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, focal-statistics

I can't seem to figure out why ArcGIS Pro won't use the weights I have stored in my kernel file to create the neighborhood for focal statistics. My kernel file is .txt and the variable contains the full file path.

My kernel file looks like this:

```
3 3
-1 -1 -1
-1  8 -1
-1 -1 -1
```

My code is as follows:

```
fn = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, kernel_filename)
nb = arcpy.sa.NbrWeight(inKernelFile=fn)
print(nb.inKernelFile)

Out: C:\python\week_07\data\sharpen.txt


out_raster = arcpy.sa.FocalStatistics(in_raster=input_raster, 
                                  neighborhood=nb, 
                                  statistics_type='mean')
```

Prof says that the correct statistics for this are as follows:

Min -734.0

Max 799.0

Mean    -2.4387200221458e-17

Standard deviation  14.610226688671

But here is what my code is giving me:

```
print('Min:', out_raster.minimum)
print('Max', out_raster.maximum)
print('Mean', out_raster.mean)
print('Standard deviation', out_raster.standardDeviation)

Out:
Min: 0.0
Max 255.0
Mean 47.55674749653172
Standard deviation 39.345867420661286
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT: As someone pointed out, using mean in focal statistics will ignore negative numbers. The solution was to use 'SUM' rather than 'MEAN' for the statistics type.

Comment: Thank you, I think I figured it out! It turns out I needed to use SUM rather than MEAN. I will update my post.

Comment: Please do not place your answer inside the Question. If the provided Answer led you to the solution you can post a second, more detailed Answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [How Focal Statistics works](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-focal-statistics-works.htm) page you'll see:

> The following apply for the kernel file for a weight neighborhood:
>
> - ...
> - For the mean and standard deviation statistics, a weight can be any
>   positive integer or floating point value. Negative values are not
>   allowed for these statistics, so any position with a negative weight
>   will be ignored in the calculations."